# Adding an additional variable to a paypal email link

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm using a paypal button link, and trying to pass arguments to it for the IPN listener.

(I passed them like this: www.paypal.com/.../&name1=value1&name2=value2)

The payment is done fine, and my IPN Listener is called.

The thing is, those additional parameters are not getting into my IPN listener.

Does anyone know how can I pass them, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were going to do it that way you would actually include those URL parameters on the end of your NotifyURL as opposed to the PayPal URL.  I wouldn't recommend doing it that way, though, because it can cause issues depending on the values of the parameters.

Instead, you can use the single CUSTOM parameter in your button code and put an NVP string in there.  That would come back in IPN as $_POST['custom'] and then you could parse the individual parameters and values back out of that.

Another option would be to save the order details in your database prior to sending the user over to PayPal.  You can then include the order ID from your database in the button code using the INVOICE parameter, and again, that would come back in IPN as $_POST['invoice'].  At that point you can hit your database to pull the data you need back out based on that record ID and processing it accordingly.